# Firebase snapshot.val() returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Im trying to retrieve a user from firebase DB but when I print the snapshot.val() it shows [object Object]. How can I print the real data? Thanks!

```js
  FriendlyChat.prototype.getRandomInterlocutor = async function(){
var numberOfUsers = await this.getNumberOfUsersRef();

var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfUsers);
if(randomIndex == 0){
  randomIndex = 1;
}

var ref = await firebase.database().ref('companies/' + this.company + '/users/');
ref.limitToFirst(randomIndex).once('value').then(snapshot =>
{
    var user = snapshot.val();
    console.log('getRandomInterlocutor = ' + user); 
    return user;
});
  }

FriendlyChat.prototype.onAuthStateChanged = function(user) {
  console.log('entro a onAuthStateChanged');
  this.interlocutor = this.getRandomInterlocutor();
  console.log(this.interlocutor);
}
```

Comment: just console.log(user) to find the structure of user object.

Answer (score 1):

Just print `console.log(user);` and not a string with the obj in it.
this reproduce it:

```
var obj = [{a: 1}, {a: 'lucas', b: 2}];
console.log('current obj', obj);
```

However as user is an array, you can just do this to get each objet as you want it. (ES6)

```
user.forEach((u, key) => {
    // u contains your user data object which is like u.uid and u.email or whatever keys you got.
    console.log(key, 'key here contains the strange "firebase array index key"');
    console.log(u);
});
```

Comment: thanks but Im confused. It prints Object { SEV9iTd8whgf0VyIbqUiVNaTcAL2: Object }. How can I set a variable = 'SEV9iTd8whgf0VyIbqUiVNaTcAL2'?

Comment: that is because firebase got strange arrays, its like objects instead of arrays so that `SEV...` is the key for the object below and not an index as you would have in a regular array. So you need like to write `user['SEV9iTd8whgf0VyIbqUiVNaTcAL2']` to get user. I know its strange in the beginning, but as more as you use it the more 'clearer' it gets

Comment: This blogpost is a good resource to understand firebase arrays better: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html